# What is the probability of selecting some item i, x times before some item j is ever selected, when there are n items?

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

Story is I am making races from a set of 220 cars. I "randomly" select a subset of cars to race and tabulate. I notice that some cars have appeared 6-7 times while others have never appeared. How likely is that? Is it truly random?

I understand the base of this. In a coin you can get 7 in a row with a probability of [2 / (2^7)]. But once I go to 3 items, I get lost.

Thanks

Comment: Let's say you're counting the number of times car $1$ appeared before car $2$ in a subset you chose. If you create three "states" $\{\text{Neither included, Car 1 included but Car 2 not included, Car 2 included}\}$ and create random variables $X_n$ whose state at time $n$ will be whatever happened when you chose cars for the $n$th race, then it looks like you have a Markov chain set up in place. If you furthermore make the third state absorbing, then you're looking at the average number of visits to a certain vertex before absorption. Formulas are known for this distribution.

Comment: Unfortunately, discussing these will require explaining what a Markov chain is and how to set it up.

Comment: Ok I have looked up Markov Chains but I do not understand the "state" concept here. Markov seems to be about being in a scenario and looking forward. My scenario is whether I picked the last car or not. The thing is once I picked the car, it is over, there is no forward. I don't know I am lost on this one.

Comment: That's why that particular car being picked, would be modelled as an *absorbing* state : one that you cannot get out of. The Markov chain will be modeled in such a way that once it hits that state where you pick car $2$ ,it will be stuck at that particular state. The question then will be : what is the average number of visits to the state where car $2$ is not picked but car $1$ is picked, before any visit to the state where car $2$ is picked first. I will see if I can squeeze in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is back of the envelope.  I expect a maximum of about $11$ repeats by the time the last car is used, after about 1200 selections.  That is $1200/R$ races, where R is the number of cars in a race.

Suppose you end up making $kn$ selections.  The chance a specific number is never chosen is $$\left(1-\frac1n\right)^{kn}\approx e^{-k}$$
The chance all of them have been chosen is around
$$1-\left(1-e^{-k}\right)^n$$
This grows from $0$ to $1$ when $k\approx\ln n$.
At that point, each item has been picked around $\ln n$ times.  I haven't worked it out, but since the minimum count is about $\ln n$ below the mean, the maximum would be about $\ln n$ above the mean, or about $2\ln n$

Comment: This seems super elegant. I don't think the last sentence makes sense. When n is large very unlikely things are more likely to happen. It can't just be "Double" the mean for any n. However, everything else makes super sense and the results seem super intuitive. Thanks

Comment: I am thinking about central limit theorem. The number of picks will be normal so same distance on each side?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. This is what I got so far. Let's first eliminate one car. He never got picked. n*(n-1/n)^s where n is the pop of cars and s is the number of selections.

Second let's figure out how many times we are getting picked. (n -1) * the number of picks for one particular car... And that is... Sumation ((n-2)/(n-1))^s + (1/(n-1))*((n-2)/(n-1))^(s-1)+ ... Until all the s are transfered from losses to wins.

Finally I have to combine these two things somehow. That's where I'm at.

I understand that the race size might impacts this but I am not ready for that. When race size approaches N sure everything changes but small races is close enough to individual selections. For my case it is 31 per race. Also I am reducing n by 2 after each race. But that is super complex. The former should decrease the overall number of repeaters and decrease the hold outs by the same amount. The latter increases repeaters a d decreases holdouts.

My current stats is that after 28 races I have 8 time repeaters and at least one hold out.  But forget all that I am just trying to understand the base case for constant n.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).